# How to ensure collision resistance in JWT claims?

Tags: authentication, hash, cryptography, jwt, access-token

I am looking at adding a scope claim to my JWT so I can know a user's roles/permissions without having to hit the db. I was reading up on the rfc7519 spec and it says:

> Claim Names can be defined at will by those using JWTs.  However, in
>   order to prevent collisions, any new Claim Name should either be
>   registered in the IANA "JSON Web Token Claims" registry established
>   by Section 10.1 or be a Public Name: a value that contains a
>   Collision-Resistant Name.

"scope" does not appeared to be registered with IANA, and I'm confused about how to evaluate collision resistance. ObjectIds and URLs are apparently ok, but i'm not sure what properties they have that make them more collision resistant than other strings.

Also which part of the claim needs to be "collision resistant", is it the key, the value or both?

How important is it to ensure collision resistance and how can I measure it? (in the context of jwt claims)

Comment: I read the spec but i don't understand what cause collision, would you mind explain a bit more? Didn't these JWT keep in localstorage for each particular website? If it has collision, is it collision to what? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the key that needs to be collision resistant as that is what you'll be querying in your authorization code.

We've defined our role claims like:

```
public const string RoleType = "http://schemas.<companyname>.com/platform/claims/role";
```

Using your company name in a URI should make it unique, given you don't happen to share the company name.